# How to load into specific path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have an app directory looks like

```
app/
├── controllers
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
├── errors.js
├── models
│   └── user.js
└── other_things
```

in the `server.js` i have the following code using [**express-load**](https://github.com/jarradseers/express-load)

```
load('errors', {cwd: 'app'})
  .then('models')
  .then('controllers')
  .into(app);
```

but `console.log(app.errors)` is `undefined`

and `console.log(app);` show the following among many other unrelated output

```
'': { errors: { not_found: [Function] } } }
```

how do i convert that to be

```
'errors':{ not_found: [Function] } }
```

the `errors.js` is defined as following

```
exports.not_found = function(err){
  //... yada yada...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution work prior to **express-load 1.1.14**:

```
load('app/errors').into(app, function(err, instance){
  app.errors = app.app.errors;
  delete app.app;
});

load('models', {cwd: 'app'}).then('controllers').into(app);
```

**and it was fixed in version 1.1.14**